# reinstalling windows 8.1 on dual boot system

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1, multi-boot

i've two operatig systems installed on my pc, 1) windows 8.1 and 2) windows 7.

now i want to reinstall windows 8.1 without uninstalling windows and 7 and vice versa,

means is it possible to install windows 7 without deleting windows 8.1 and also is it possible to install windows 8.1 without deleting windows 7.

Please let me know in this regards.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you mean here. I assume that you want to reinstall both Windows 7 and 8 without losing your data?
For Windows 8 there is a refresh option in  **PC Settings>Update and Recovery>Recovery.**

However for Windows 7 there is no such option therefore you must first backup your files, do a clean install then load your files back. Or you could use the installation disk if you still have it and install Windows 7 with **Install Now > Upgrade.** (Be sure to backup first first to be safe).

Note that you'll need to reinstall Windows 7 first **then** Windows 8 otherwise your Win8 won't be detected and you'll have to go through some extra steps.